# Review Commenting/Auditing Issue - "You didn't pass"

Tags: bug, comments, review-audits

My first failed audit was today (as I've read a number of posts to start out this way). When I see a question that I personally have knowledge on, I will comment on it to further the question. Well, I did this, and was preparing to press the "No Action Needed" button afterward, but then I was greeted with the "You didn't pass" message.

This is very irritating - why does the review system assume that a comment **must** mean I'm critiquing the post due to something about it being low quality? Is the review logic set up in a way that I would have to open the question outside the review panel to add comments about the actual question itself? That just seems daft.

Comment: For reference, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30049962/why-is-the-alphabet-split-into-multiple-ranges-in-this-c-code) was the audit question, to which I posted a comment.